# Efficient macro looping in SAS to get to Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, macros, sas

I'm using SAS to access an Oracle database. The problem is that the function / stored procedure lives on one server in Oracle - which is fine when my data lives there too - but when the data is on a different server I still want to use that function.  So I loaded some macros with the personal id's to pass them to the function in a loop.  It works, but it's painfully slow.  I don't need 'optimal', just 'reasonable'...my datasets will max around 100,000 rows. I've read that creating a dataset is one of the most resource intensive jobs in SAS, so I'm experimenting with creating an empty table and insert into, but I haven't noticed much gain yet.

So the question is - can I use the Oracle stored procedures for data on a different server in a reasonable amount of time within SAS?  (Either by improving my existing approach or something completely different)

My first attempt (around 25 minutes for 13,000 personal id's):

```
%MACRO STATE() ; 
options nosource nonotes; 
%* 2. get macro max loop n; 
proc sql noprint; 
select left(put(count(distinct pidm),10.)) into :loopn from examp
;quit;

%* 3. load macros with the pidms of interest;
proc sql noprint; 
select distinct pidm into :pidm1 - :pidm&loopn from examp order by pidm; 
quit;


%Do i = 1 %TO &loopn ;                            /*build em */
%* %put **************LOOP &i OF &loopn *********************;
proc sql noprint; 
connect to oracle as mycon(user=xxxxxx password=xxxxxxx path='PROD') ; 
create table subsetdat&i as
select * from connection to mycon 
  (select %quote(&&pidm&i) as pidm ,UILIB.ADDR.STATE(&&pidm&i, 'MA') as state  
from dual); 
  disconnect from mycon ; 
 ; quit;

%END;
data state; set subsetdat1-subsetdat&loopn  ;             /*stack 'em */

%Do j = 1 %TO &loopn ;                          /*drop 'em */
proc sql ; 
drop table subsetdat&j
;
%END;
options source notes; 
%MEND STATE ; 

options nomprint; 

%STATE() ;
```

Comment: I don't know anything about SAS, but it looks like you are opening and closing a connection within a loop.  Is that correct?

Comment: I'm assuming that UILIB.ADDR.STATE(&&pidm&i, 'MA') is your custom function? What does it do? Any chance of bringing that portion into SAS?

Comment: It returns the state portion of a mailing address.  This is just one of many functions I wish to access.  I googled and there appear to be ways to copy "stored procedures" / functions in Oracle among servers, I didn't find any way to copy into SAS.  So sorry - no copy/paste code example for you, I do try to do that usually.

Comment: If you have the appropriate licenses can look into proc geocode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move to loop inside the `proc sql`, thereby removing the overhead of creating multiple datasets from multiple pass-through queries, and use a `union all` to 'stack' the individual query results together.

```
%MACRO STATE() ; 
options nosource nonotes; 
/* 2. get macro max loop n; */
proc sql noprint; 
select left(put(count(distinct pidm),10.)) into :loopn from examp
;quit;

/* 3. load macros with the pidms of interest; */
proc sql noprint; 
select distinct pidm into :pidm1 - :pidm&loopn from examp order by pidm; 
quit;

/* Build single pass-thru query with multiple select ... union all select ... etc */
proc sql noprint; 
  connect to oracle as mycon(user=xxxxxx password=xxxxxxx path='PROD') ; 
  create table state as
  select * from connection to mycon 
    (%DO I = 1 %TO &loopn ;                            /*build em */
     select %quote(&&pidm&i) as pidm ,UILIB.ADDR.STATE(&&pidm&i, 'MA') as state from dual
       %IF &I lt &LOOPN %THEN %DO ; /* if not last iteration do a `union all` */
       union all
       %END ;
     %END ;
    ) ;
  disconnect from mycon ; 
quit;
options source notes; 
%MEND STATE ; 

options nomprint; 

%STATE() ;
```

Comment: I re-ran on those 13,000 pidms - took less than 10 seconds.  Many thanks.